# How to change font and reskin layout of iPhone/iOS iPod in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipod

I would like to build a customized iPod app for my iPhone.

Does anyone knows how to change/reskin the layout in any aspect (font size, color, icons) of the 
iPod library in xcode? Or is there an alternative framework out there?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use custom graphics if you want to "skin" your app. There is no framework that I know of that will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks. Can I access the iPod Music library programmatically and display the infos in lists etc?

Comment: Yes you can access the iPod library.